# How to get the totals to display in a calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

so i have made a calculator for my work that sees how much we could save potential clients. All works well, but i cant get the total fee's for all of the boxes to appear. I just don't think i know the right process to get all the "total monthly savings" to add up at the end.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snn5vhg2/

**Here is the page:**http://176.32.230.46/sarahmcdonald.com/files/index.html

**And here is the code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>First Data Calculator</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<style type="text/css">

body{
background-color:#e5e5e5;
}

#container{
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#main{
margin-bottom:50px;
font-size:3em;
text-decoration:underline;
}

#VISABOX{
display:inline-block;
width:238px;
background-color:#fce4d1;
padding:15px;
border-radius:6px;
height:238px;
border:#c9c9c9 solid 1px;
}

.boxes{
display:inline-block;
margin-left:20px;
vertical-align:top; 
width:238px;
background-color:#fce4d1;
padding:15px;
height:238px;
border-radius:6px;
border:#c9c9c9 solid 1px;
}


.titles{
margin:0 0 0 8px;
}


.inputs{
margin:7px;
height:25px;
width:200px;
}

 .words{
margin:7px 0 0 8px ; 
}

 .calculators{
margin:7px;
height:25px;
border-radius:5px;
background-color:#F3F3F3;
}

#totals{
margin:30px 0 0 5px;
font-size:1.3em;
}

#finishButton{
font-size:1.3em;
border-radius:7px;
background-color:#F3F3F3;
}



</style>  


</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<h1 id="main">Fee Calculator</h1>

<div id="VISABOX" >
<h4 id="VISA" class="titles">Visa</h4>
<input id="vVol" class="inputs" type="text" placeholder="Visa Volume..."/><br>
<input id="vFees" class="inputs" type="text" placeholder="Visa Fees..."/><br>

<button id="vCalc" class="calculators"> Calculate </button>
<p id="vEMDR" class="words">EMDR=<span id="vEMDRSPAN"></span></p>
<p id="vMonthly" class="words">Monthly Savings=<span id="vMonthlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="vYearly" class="words">Yearly Savings=<span id="vYearlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="vFive" class="words">Five Year Savings=<span id="vFiveSpan"></span></p>
</div>




<div id="MCBOX" class="boxes">
<h4 id="MC" class="titles">MasterCard</h4>
<input id="mcVol" class="inputs" type="text" placeholder="MC Volume..."/><br>
<input id="mcFees" class="inputs" type="text" placeholder="MC Fees..."/><br>

<button id="mcCalc" class="calculators"> Calculate </button>
<p id="mcEMDR" class="words">EMDR=<span id="mcEMDRSPAN"></span></p>
<p id="mcMonthly" class="words">Monthly Savings=<span id="mcMonthlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="mcYearly" class="words">Yearly Savings=<span id="mcYearlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="mcFive" class="words">Five Year Savings=<span id="mcFiveSpan"></span></p>
</div>




<div id="IDPBOX" class="boxes">
<h4 id="IDP" class="titles">Interac</h4>
<input id="idpTrans" type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="# of Trans..."/><br>
<input id="idpFees" type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="IDP Fees..."/><br>

<button id="idpCalc" class="calculators"> Calculate </button>
<p id="idpPerTran" class="words">Per Tran=<span id="idpPerTranSpan"></span></p>
<p id="idpMonthly" class="words">Monthly Savings=<span id="idpMonthlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="idpYearly" class="words">Yearly Savings=<span id="idpYearlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="idpFive" class="words">Five Year Savings=<span id="idpFiveSpan"></span></p>
</div>

<div id="OCBOX" class="boxes">
<h4 id="OC" class="titles"> Other Charges </h4>
<input id="otherCharges" type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="Total Other Charges..." /><br>
<input id="ourCharges" type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="Our Other Charges..." /><br>
<button id="ocCalc" class="calculators"> Calculate </button>

<p id="ocMonthly" class="words"> Monthly Savings=<span id="ocMonthlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="ocYearly" class="words">Yearly Savings=<span id="ocYearlySpan"></span></p>
<p id="ocFive" class="words">Five Year Savings=<span id="ocFiveSpan"></span></p>
</div>

<div id="totals">
<button id="finishButton"> Finish </button>
<p id="monthlyTotal"> Monthly Total Savings=<span id="monthlyTotalSpan"></span></p>
<p id="yearlyTotal"> Total Yearly Savings=</p>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("vCalc").onclick=function(){

        var visaVol=document.getElementById("vVol").value;
        var visaFees=document.getElementById("vFees").value;
        var visaEMDR;
        visaEMDR=(visaFees/visaVol*100).toFixed(2);

        var visaMonthly=(visaFees-(visaVol*.0171)).toFixed(2);
        var visaYearly=(visaMonthly*12).toFixed(2);
        var visaFive=(visaYearly*5).toFixed(2);

        document.getElementById("vMonthlySpan").innerHTML=" "+visaMonthly+"$";
        document.getElementById("vYearlySpan").innerHTML=" "+visaYearly+"$";
        document.getElementById("vFiveSpan").innerHTML=" "+visaFive+"$";
        document.getElementById("vEMDRSPAN").innerHTML=" "+visaEMDR+"%";

    }

    document.getElementById("mcCalc").onclick=function(){

        var mcVol=document.getElementById("mcVol").value;
        var mcFees=document.getElementById("mcFees").value;
        var mcEMDR=(mcFees/mcVol*100).toFixed(2);

        var mcMonthly=(mcFees-(mcVol*.0178)).toFixed(2);
        var mcYearly=(mcMonthly*12).toFixed(2);
        var mcFive=(mcYearly*5).toFixed(2);

        document.getElementById("mcMonthlySpan").innerHTML=" "+mcMonthly+"$";
        document.getElementById("mcYearlySpan").innerHTML=" "+mcYearly+"$";
        document.getElementById("mcFiveSpan").innerHTML=" "+mcFive+"$";
        document.getElementById("mcEMDRSPAN").innerHTML=" "+mcEMDR+"%";

    }


    document.getElementById("idpCalc").onclick=function(){

        var debitTrans=document.getElementById("idpTrans").value;
        var debitFees=document.getElementById("idpFees").value; 
        var perTran=(debitFees/debitTrans).toFixed(2);

        var debitMonthly=(debitFees-(debitTrans*.04)).toFixed(2);
        var debitYearly=(debitMonthly*12).toFixed(2);
        var debitFive=(debitYearly*5).toFixed(2);

        document.getElementById("idpPerTranSpan").innerHTML=" "+perTran+"$";
        document.getElementById("idpMonthlySpan").innerHTML=" "+debitMonthly+"$";
        document.getElementById("idpYearlySpan").innerHTML=" "+debitYearly+"$";
        document.getElementById("idpFiveSpan").innerHTML=" "+debitFive+"$";
    }


    document.getElementById("ocCalc").onclick=function(){
        var otherFees=document.getElementById("otherCharges").value;
        var ourFees=document.getElementById("ourCharges").value;

        var ocMonthlySav=(otherFees-ourFees).toFixed(2);
        var ocYearlySav=(ocMonthlySav*12).toFixed(2);
        var ocFiveSav=(ocYearlySav*5).toFixed(2);

        document.getElementById("ocMonthlySpan").innerHTML=" "+ocMonthlySav+"$";
        document.getElementById("ocYearlySpan").innerHTML=" "+ocYearlySav+"$";
        document.getElementById("ocFiveSpan").innerHTML=" "+ocFiveSav+"$";
    }

document.getElementById("finishButton").onclick=function(){
    var monTotal=   

    document.getElementById("monthlyTotalSpan").innerHTML=" "+monTotal+"$";
}   

</script>
```

Comment: where you want to display total?

Comment: `var monTotal= ` what come in this variable?

Comment: We're a cautious lot and don't like clicking on URLs. I created a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/snn5vhg2/

Comment: var monTotal= is where i want to have the total of the other 4 totals show up.

Comment: For monthly, you need the sum of the innerHTMLs of `vMonthlySpan`, `mcMonthlySpan`, `idpMonthlySpan` and `ocMonthlySpan`.  Everything you need is pretty much already in your code.

Comment: @adamdc78 I tried that, but it came up 'NaN'... because thats what i tried in the beginning. heres a JSFiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/SarahMcDiddy/8emdczmy/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you just quit when you are 90% finished (hopefully not).

But to finish up you needed to grab the values from the `xxMonthlySpan` and `xxYearlySpan` tags, convert them to floats, add them together, and then change the `innerHTML` of the `span` tags in the end.

You also did not have `<span id="yearlyTotalSpan"></span>` so I added that in just to be consistent with everything else you had.

I also rounded to two decimal places for the year total.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkx8h3hy/

Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Looks like i was missing the parsefloat, i have not learnt that yet. 

So when i did the .value , i got NaN. And when i did the .innerHTML, i just got all the totals listed, not added. Is the parse float a necessity in this case or is there a way to do it with .value?

Comment: So `innerHTML` is returned as a string. `parseFloat` just turns it into a decimal number.

Comment: That's awesome to know! So just for future reference, should I have used parseFloat in the calculations with the inputs as well? Instead of getting the .value?

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful.